# Android NDK - Where to put the .so file which specified in LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES?

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I have successfully build libcurl for android as a shared library, both armeabi-v7a and x86, and one of my project depends on it. I have set "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcurl", the problem is where should I put those libcurl.so files?

I tried putting them under (project)/jni/lib/(platform)/libcurl.so, and ndk-build gives me a whole load of linking error. (project)/lib/(platform)/libcurl.so will not work too because ndk-build will clear this directory before build.

So I tried again, building 1 platform at a time, however I still have no idea where to put it. jni/libcurl.so will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, follow this, download curl source from http://curl.haxx.se/

```
  - prepare the toolchain of the Android NDK for standalone use; this can
    be done by invoking the script:

    ./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh
    which creates a usual cross-compile toolchain. Lets assume that you put
    this toolchain below /opt then invoke configure with something like:

    export PATH=/opt/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/bin:$PATH

    ./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi [more configure options]

    make
```

Done.